# Clicking on link does not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use Firefox 36 on Windows 7. I am seeing a strange problem where the product that i work on, javascript suddenly stops working on FF 36. I do not see any errors in the console when it stops working too. For eg: empty drop down list, missing hover icons, unable to click on links, links or button disappearing. The same on IE11 and chrome work fine. Is there a way I can figure out why this is a problem on FF-36?

Comment: And your question is? Also, how about posting your code so we have *some* idea what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the above problem because I had Firebug turned ON and that disabled javascript on the page. Disabling firebug and refreshing the page enabled the javascript again.